# Is it possible to set storage rules using firestore of Firebase?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

So I'm trying to set rules into storage, but I need to access to firestore to set it right.

**Here is my example:**

Into my firestore database I have a `users` collection which have a collection named `items`. The path look like this: `/users/items/{itemId}`

I want that a user can read and write a file into storage with this path: `/items/{id}/file.png` only if the `{id}` of the item already exist into the `items` collection of firestore database.
Is there a way to set correctly rules into storage using firestore ?

I tried this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /items/{item}/{allPaths=**} {
        allow read, write: if exists(/databases/{database}/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/items/$(item));
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work :/

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update (Oct 2022): it **is** now possible to access Cloud Firestore from within your Cloud Storage security rules with the new `firestore.get()` and `firestore.exists()` function. See the blog post [Announcing cross-service Security Rules](https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/09/announcing-cross-service-security-rules) and the documentation on [enhancing Cloud Storage security rules with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/rules-conditions#enhance_with_firestore).

Previous answer: 
<strike>There is no way for security rules of one Firebase product to refer to another Firebase product. The performance implications would be too big.</strike>

If such inter-product consistency is a requirement for you, you might want to consider doing the writes from Cloud Functions. While that doesn't suddenly allow cross-product security rules, it does mean that you an ensure it is *your* code doing the writes and the code is running in a more reliable environment then the average user's phone or PC.

Comment: Hey Frank, is it possible to access the non default Firestore database using the Storage rules?

Comment: Given that you specify the full path in `firestore.exists(/databases/(default)/documents/users/$(uid));`, I'd expect that you can replace `(default)` with the database ID that you want to access - but I haven't tried it. If you can't get that to work, post a new question with a minimal repro.

Comment: As of today, this actually works, despite the rule simulator doesn't accept firestore.
Also, `(default)` can be kept in the path.