# Limit Google Cloud Storage Access to Followers (stored in Firestore)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a social network. It will use a follow/unfollow model. Profiles can be public or private (like Twitter or Instagram).

Users can create photos that will be stored in **Google Cloud Storage**. Database is being handled by **Google Firestore**.

**Currently my Storage hierarchy is**

bucket / users / {userId} / images***

### My question is: How do I limit access to a certain user's photos using Cloud Storage Security Rules?

I'd like people to only be able to view another's photos if:

```
1. they are following that user, or
2. the user is public
```

This seems like a super common use case but have not been able to find any answers on it. I've seen other questions on it but they don't solve the problem.

[Is it possible to set storage rules using firestore of Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053399/is-it-possible-to-set-storage-rules-using-firestore-of-firebase)

Or

[Can Firebase Cloud Storage rules validate against Firestore data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861983/can-firebase-cloud-storage-rules-validate-against-firestore-data)

- [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) talks about using [custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk) to set access. In his example he uses "guilds" (which could substitute for a user's followers) such as `admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {guild1: true})`
- But this won't work for someone who's following hundreds or thousands of accounts. You'd need to have each userId that a user follows and set it to true. E.g. user1 follows user2/user3/user4/user5/user6/user7/user8....user1000. That's a lot of data to cram into a token (and "Custom claims payload must not exceed 1000 bytes.")
- You'd need some other method for public profiles.

I also looked at the official documentation, the only sort of relevant example reiterates the same custom tokens for groups (which doesn't work for reasons stated above):

- Group private (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security)

### Please let me know if you have any suggestions to limiting access to a follow/unfollow model (public/private) using Cloud Storage Security Rules.

Comment: I can give the little instrustions only as per the real time database of firebase you can structure your data like as follwers node under it user ids and uder these ids the follwers id so user post can be read the its self or root.child(followers).child($uid).exist add this rule under the user_posts same like this you can apply on you collections or data

Comment: You misread the question. I need to implement Cloud Storage Security Rules to limit access (and they don't interoperate with databases). I know how to use security rules for my database using Firestore Security Rules.